# Removing item in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I was trying to implement a feature as description: Every item in RecyclerView will be removed after 5 seconds. My code as below:

```
new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
    @Override public void onTick(long l) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Ticking: " + l);
        for (int i = 0, dataLength = mComments.size(); i < dataLength; i++{
            RoomMessage item = mComments.get(i);
            // item.timeRemaining initial value is 5000
            item.timeRemaining -= 1000;
            if (item.timeRemaining <= 0) {
                mComments.remove(i);
                notifyItemRemoved(i);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override public void onFinish() {
        start();
    }
}.start();
```

The app crashes with error message says like `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4`
What was wrong?

Comment: can you provide full log?

Comment: If your size is 4, your index range is [0,.. 3]. You cannot remove what is not appended to list.

Comment: @adnbsr Yes and I'm pretty sure the range is in [0..3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your for loop.

```
    for (int i = 0, dataLength = mComments.size(); i < dataLength; i++)
```

dataLength will be initialized only once (same as of i) and then that value will be used for next iterations. So, if the list size is initially 4, then dataLength will be 4 throughout wherein the list size will keep decreasing which will cause **IndexOutOfBoundsException**.

Change the for statement as below:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mComments.size(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is  `mComments.remove(i);` with `for`
when you remove an item durate a interation the `for` crash. 
you need replace the `for` by `enter code here`, like this:

```
    Iterator iterator = mComments.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        RoomMessage item = iterator.next();
        mComments.remove(item);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```